Want info about 80s american TV series
I want to get name and info of a 80s TV series and I don't remember its name and their cast & crew names.
What I remember is that, there was a group of friends, some of them has some special powers.
For Example:

One man has electric power (a man can charge himself and shoot a light with his hands).
One man can be small or big any time (he is a black man).

Note:
They have an Ice Cream Van also and it's a family series not like (crank).

This is is “Misfits of Science” from the early 1980s.  The electricity powers and the shrinking man are both elements of the show. 

thank you, thank you, thank you
